# Auto Opening USB

Tags: macos, usb, automator

I would really like to make that I can plug in a USB into a mac with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format and an application automatically opens.
I know this works on Windows with Command Prompt (Cmd)
I'm not sure but maybe this would work with Automator Folder action

[image: Automator Folder Action]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the following links:

- https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24748
  and
- https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32534

In the first one they use `launchd`